# friends not showing up in GameKit sandbox

Tags: iphone, friend, gamekit

I am perplexed by a behaviour I am getting in the GameKit sandbox.

It worked very nicely in joining two devices (an iPhone and an iPad) some weeks ago, and those devices still work with one another smoothly.

I have tried to add a new friend on a third device, but only one account (the account which accepted the friend request) recognizes the other account as a friend.

On the non-recognizing device, there is a hint of recognition: on the 'sandbox' page, the flag graphic displays 0 friends, pauses, and then changes to 1 friend.  But on the 'friends' page -- no friends.

Has anyone else seen a similar behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Log out of the sandbox account.. close gamecenter, including close it if running in background.. and open again.. It will prompt you to sign in again.. and you add friends again..

Sometimes gamecenter gets confused over the accounts.. Happens to me too..

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'll keep trying.  I think I may have caused a problem when I logged in on the third device using (my wife's) real iTunes account, forgetting that for the dev sandbox I shouldn't use a real account... I probably must make a clean restart on all devices when there's time for that...